# How to double split string in PHP?

Tags: php, split

I have problem that I can't solve even hours searching for answer in Google.

I have string for example:

```
$string = "___username1,password1___username2,password2";
```

I need to split string from "___" then save result into variable and then split it again from every "," so result should be:

From first split result:

```
$s[0] = username1,password1
$s[1] = username2,passwrod2
```

And from second split I need to get result like:

```
username1
password1
username2
password2
```

I tried:

```
$s0 = explode("___",$string);
$s1 = explode(",",$s0);
```

Error:

> Warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given

Could you help me please?

Comment: Did you try the obvious and loop through the array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there with the `explode()` using `___` as the delimiter.  You can then use 2 things, `array_map()` to process the result with the callback as `str_getcsv` as each part is a comma separated list.

As the string starts with the delimiter, this uses `array_shift()` to remove the blank entry off the start...

```
$final = array_map("str_getcsv", explode("___", $string));
array_shift($final);
print_r($final);
```

gives...

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => username1
            [1] => password1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => username2
            [1] => password2
        )

)
```

Answer (score -2):

I am not sure about the best practice but maybe we could replace "_" to something else.

```
    $s[0] = str_replace("___","*+*",$string);
    $s[0] = explode("*+*",$string);
```

Comment: Why are you replacing the pattern?